# Is JRE 1.7 able to run 1.8 jars?

Tags: java

I have two jars: CLI.jar and Some.jar; CLI.jar depends on Some.jar.

The major version of CLI.jar classes is 51 (Java 7)
The major version of Some.jar classes is 52(Java 8)

I run **java -jar CLI.jar** with JRE 1.7 on a host, it gave "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" error.
I initially thought it was a JRE version issue, but when I switched to another host which also had JRE 1.7, I did not see this error and everything worked fine.

What did I miss here? I am a professional software developer and I know the basics and double checked the JRE version I am using.

Comment: *What did I miss here?* - perhaps you ran with 1.8 on that other host, despite of having 1.7 somewhere.

Comment: No, I double checked on the other host. java -version gives "1.7.0_251"

Comment: Are they available for testing? Strictly said, StackOverflow mandates reproducibility of issues that much that if I write `[mre]` here without code formatting, it automatically expands to a link, [mre].

Answer (score 0):

JRE 1.7 is not able to run 1.8 class files (and, by extension, JARs that require 1.8 class files). The error you have encountered points that out quite well.

If another computer can run the same JAR file, its Java version is not 1.8. Note that multiple JREs can be installed on one machine.

Comment: `java -version`
 
`java version "1.7.0_251"`

Comment: In that case, it is possible that only some classes in your JAR are at level 52.0, and those classes are not requires on the other host. Or possibly you have a startup script which explicitly specifies another JRE. Whatever the reason is why your JAR works on that other host, it is NOT because Java 1.7 can run Java 1.8-compiled classes.

Comment: It is the same set of jars. I don't know what you mean by " those classes are not requires on the other host".. they have the same dependency graph and are used in the same way. I knew what you said and I am asking this question because what I saw on the hosts contradicted it.

Comment: A JAR contains a bunch of class files. Which one of them are loaded into the JVM depends on the execution of the program. The execution of the program may depend on things like configuration, the OS you are on, the input files, or a bunch of other things. But without solid information on which program you are running and how you are running it, all of this is speculation.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - **No**, Java byte code is not forward compatible, but it **is** backwards compatible.

---

**A bit more details:**

Generally, files compiled with later Java version can't be run on the earlier Java machines (e.g. classes compiled with Jdk 1.8 can't be run with Jdk 1.7).

However, this statement is false in the way around context. Any version of Jdk is inherently, and by design, backwards compatible<sup>1</sup>, which means, that Jdk 1.8 can run programs compiled with compiler from Jdk 1.7.

---

<sup>1</sup>*There is a little catch here. It's rare, but sometimes, later Java versions deprecate and then finally remove some APIs, Frameworks, Libraries or etc. from the build. For example, JavaFX has been removed since Java 11. So, if this kind of situation arises, and you upgrade your Java, you'll just need to manually add missing (in this case - JavaFX) dependency.*

Comment: I know the exactly same as you said but what I saw contradicted it.. otherwise I won't be asking the question here...

Comment: @Jeff relax, first of all. I just saw your updated question, and I couldn't imagine it without reading, what you tackle at. Can you include both machines' Java 7 versions exactly? is the project you're having this problem with a Maven project?

Comment: I build the project using Gradle. Let me check and i will update

Comment: failed one is 1.7.0_261 and succeeed one is 1.7.0_251

Comment: @Jeff did you solve it? I believe there has to be some other JVM instance running on either machine.

Comment: could not RCA. We upgraded java for our fleet.